# variable create in function call to use it in foreach loop in php

Tags: php

I have a the following code in php:

```
    foreach($lines as $num=>value){
    fixIndex();
    if ($num <$i)continue;


   function fixIndex(){
   static $i=0;
   static $j=1;
   if($j-$i==60)$i=$i=$i+60;
   $j++;
   return $i;
   }
```

there is no error in running the program. But the $i seems no affect. When I change it to number, i.e. 60 it will skip 60 records as I wanted.
Can anyone helps me out on this one?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to extract a slice of the array, you can use php's array_slice(). https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php . `array_slice($input, 60, -1, true)`

Answer (score 0):

Totally wrong and strange for me:

First - it's enough:

```
$i += 60; or $i = $i + 60; //you wrote $i=$i=$i+60
```

Second - use (always)

```
{} and paragraphs like this

if ($j-$i==60) {
  //body here
}
```

This is not neccessary

```
return $i;
```

because you use static var (it's not recommended too). Return is correctly if you assign result of function to variable, i.e.

```
$i = fixIndex();
```

This condition is never satisfied

```
if($j-$i==60)
```

because above this you initialize variables $i and $j every time

```
static $i=0;
static $j=1;
```

> 1 - 0 != 60, never ever!

Answer (score 0):

first I am sorry for the type mistake. It really is

```
if($j-$i==60)$i=$i+60;
$J++;
```

I agree that return $i; is not necessary. the foreach loop still more code to follow that is why } is not see yet.
According to the manual the static only set the $i and $j once. when function exit. $j is increment by 1. so after 60 call to that function. $j-$i==60 should happen. At that time $i should affected and change to 60.
My real problem is to change the value of $i that after the fixIndex function very 60 increment of $j. Any help?
Thanks very much for the prompt answer. Point it out if I do not explain clear enough for the question.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score -1):

You have syntax error  `value`  to `$value` 
and foreach not have `}`

Try this

```
foreach($lines as $num=>$value){
   fixIndex();
   if ($num <$i)continue;
}

function fixIndex(){
    static $i=0;
    static $j=1;
    if($j-$i==60)$i=$i=$i+60;
    $j++;
  return $i;
}
```